# Python list copying or delete function

Tags: python, list

My task is to reverse this list, but I can't use num.reverse(). I need to delete some elements from list, but I don't know which command is best to use. Tried:`del num[]` `num.clear()` and they didn't work!
My code:

```
num = [5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 1, 10, 15, 0]
for index in range(len(num), 0, -1):   
    num.append(num[index-1])
print(num)
```

Console now shows:

```
[5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 1, 10, 15, 0, 0, 15, 10, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3, 5]
```

But what I need to be left with is:

```
[0, 15, 10, 1, 2, 4, 7, 9, 8, 6, 3, 5]
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Best is to not try some random functions that sound about right, but to actually look up the right ones

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. By what logic do you arrive at the final result? What's the task?

Answer (score 1):

For the algorithm you're using, you need to create a new list:

```
num = [5, 3, 6, 8, 9, 7, 4, 2, 1, 10, 15, 0]
new = []
for index in range(len(num), 0, -1):   
    new.append(num[index-1])

print(new)
```

Comment: Prune, Yes I know I can do this, but I need to use same list so and i can't create a new list :(

Comment: The canonical way to do this in place is to work from both ends, swapping the elements:  `num[n], num[size-n] = num[size-n], num[n]`